# App randomly crashing

Tags: android

So I built an android app that connects to my server and sends text messages over Wi-Fi to other users. The server works fine but I cannot figure out why every time I try to use the app it crashes when I login.

logcat output:

```
canner.findPatternInBuffer(Scanner.java:1022)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1694)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1555)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at com.thatadhacker.texting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
11-27 17:13:43.089 32571-32571/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

```
public static Socket s;
public static PrintWriter out;
public static Scanner in;
public static Button login;
public static Button send;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                s = new Socket("finlaybot.soapfudge.com", 5567);
                out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            while (true) {
                text.append(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
@Override
public void onClick(final View view){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    String username = user.getText().toString();
                    String password = pass.getText().toString();
                    out.println(username);
                    out.println(password);
                    user.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    EditText to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                    out.println(to.getText().toString());
                    out.println(message.getText().toString());
                    to.setText("");
                    message.setText("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I know the server works fine because of the desktop client which works fine.
*Edit i got the logs

Comment: There is crash log info just check the logcat more thoroughly, try logcat no filters

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access/modify UI controls from a thread that is not UI/main thread. In the logs you should see something like

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

You should create a handler in the onCreate and post to that handler or use AsyncTaskLoader. That is the only issue I can think of by looking at the code. Try to attach the logs. 
Eg of handler

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button mButton;
Handler mHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mButton.setText("rushan");
                }
            });
            mButton.setText("new Text");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}